# Safe to use Windows 10 ISO to format after Windows 10 Upgrade?

Tags: windows-10

I've downloaded the Windows 10 ISO using the Windows Media Creation tool. I have also successfully upgraded to Windows 10 from my genuine Windows 8.1 install, using Microsoft's free upgrade. I understand that my install of Windows 10 after the free upgrade is "linked" to my hardware, and I no longer have access to my Windows key. Can I format my C: partition and go through a fresh install with the Windows 10 ISO while retaining my "free" genuine Windows 10?

Comment: Your question has an answer at [this post](http://superuser.com/a/947475/270195), i.e. Yes you can

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to activate Windows 10 Pro without installing previous version first?](http://superuser.com/questions/947461/how-to-activate-windows-10-pro-without-installing-previous-version-first)

Answer (score 3):

In theory you should, yes. But if your windows works, don't go through all these steps, and do it the easy way, directly from whitin Windows 10.

Open start, and search for "reset windows" and you will be able to do a clean install from that point. No hastle with entering serial keys etc.

Comment: I know of that "easy way", but it doesn't allow me to format partitions, that's why I need the ISO.

Comment: You can do a lot from Disk Management from Computer Management, including resizing and creating partitions, but yeah, in this case it might be quicker to use the ISO.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not certain about the formatting, but otherwise yes, I did it yesterday.

With Windows 10 installed over Windows 7 for a few months now, I reinstalled, keeping nothing, and Windows 10 Pro Build 10240 was installed.  There was no indication I even needed to activate Windows.  I followed that with the version 1511 update without a problem.

While I can't be 100% certain, it seems like the installer automagically formatted my C: drive and left my D: drive untouched.