# Using Windows 8.1 OEM license for Windows 10 imaging

Tags: windows, windows-10, windows-10-upgrade, license

I have several hundred computers with Windows 8.1 on it. Right now they are OEM activated as Windows 8.1 machines. I need to be able to image them with an OEM activated install of Windows 10. Is there any way to use Windows 8.1 OEM license with Windows 10?

I cannot manually upgrade each machine. I need to be able to use one image and be able to blast 20 machines at a time with it.

Comment: If you wait until Windows 10 Threshold 2 is released you can activate each machine with their own Windows 8.1 license.  Today your only choice is to upgrade each machine individually to Windows 10 from their activated Windows 8.1 installation.  There is a process which can be ran, which will generate a digital entitlement file, which can then be used.  I just don't recall what that file is.  Your are better off waiting a week for an updated .iSO if manually upgrading each machine isn't an option.

Comment: Are they Volume License or OEM keys on the computers?  If they are OEM keys they are all different keys per computer.  However if they are Volume Licenses all the computers will use one key.

Comment: @N.Greene - "they are OEM" - indicates they are not VLK keys.

Comment: @Ramhound I know, but just checking.

Comment: [I found the file.  Copy and run Run `source\gatherosstate.exe` from the .ISO;  This will generate `GenuineTicket.xml`;  Once Windows 10 is installed put it here `c:\programdata\microsoft\windows\clipsvc\genuineticket\`](http://superuser.com/questions/947461/how-to-activate-windows-10-pro-without-installing-previous-version-first/994957#994957)